# SimpleDateFormat and 2013-01-17T00:00:00-06:00

Tags: java

What would be the correct format to use in SimpleDateFormat to parse incoming dates that look like this: "2013-01-17T00:00:00-06:00"?

Comment: I know how to get the 'T' in the middle, the problem is I don't know how to get the -06:00 at the end, also it might be something else like -07:00

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The format would be like `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssX`

Answer (score 3):

This format should work:

```
"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssXXX"
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to trim the last colon to align with java's zone info format of `"-0600"`.

Try this:

```
String str = "2013-01-17T00:00:00-06:00";
new SimpleDataFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mm:ssZ").parse(str.replaceAll(":(..)$", "$1"));
```

Comment: You can use `X` instead of `Z`, to parse the date. `X` denotes `ISO 8601` Time Zone

Comment: @RohitJain You learn something evey day... Interestingly, this is not in the javadoc (I checked up to version 7)

Comment: Check the link I posted in comment on OP. It's listed in SimpleDateFormat docs.

Comment: @RohitJain (Damn. Chrome overrode my change to v7 and loaded v6 javadocs) Even so, this is new to java 7.

Comment: @Bohemian.. Yeah, should have mentioned that. :)

Answer (score 0):

yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssz

Refer This link : http://www.w3.org/TR/NOTE-datetime

Answer (score 0):

SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ");
System.out.println(sdf.format(new GregorianCalendar().getTime()));

Is that not sufficient?